# Linker Error With Static Library

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries, linker-errors, header-files

I have successufully compiled my spellcheck program and libspellcheck library. Now my problem is allowing other developers to use my libspellcheck. I created a simple test program:

```
#include <spellcheck.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    bool spell_result = check_spelling("english.dict", "abed");

    if(spell_result == true)
    {
        cout << "your dictionary / libspellcheck works!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "problem with your dictionary / libspellcheck" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If everything is functioning fine, the program will output:

your dictionary / libspellcheck works

However, this program won't even compile. I used:

g++ -lspellcheck -o test test.cpp

And it did not work. I believe this is a problem with the header file, as the compiler gives me this:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:59: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
test.cpp:9:59: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
/tmp/ccIz3ivT.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `check_spelling(char*, char*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The only problem is, spellcheck.h is located in /usr/include, which is where I believe it should be. My question is, how do I fix this error, and was a it a problem with my header file or was it a problem with my libspellcheck. If you need to look at additional code, I will gladly provide it, as spellcheck and libspellcheck are licensed under the GPL.

Comment: To fix the warnings, change `check_spelling` to take `const char*` arguments instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `check_spelling` declaration in header is correct, try this:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lspellcheck
```

(`-l` should be *after* the objects depending on the libraries in the command line). As of the header, it *is* indeed found and used, or you would get an error from the compiler, not the linker.

Comment: wow, you're right. I had no idea compilers were that picky about where different arguments go